# Jquery-mobile 1.4.5: a port to support Jquery 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery-mobile 1.4.5 does not support Jquery 3.2.1.

Jquery-mobile project seems very slow in development, and I saw some posts
saying the project is dead.

Other JS libraries in our project requires Jquery 3.2.1, but jquery-mobile 1.4.5 does not support Jquery 3.2.1. We do not want to upgrade jquery-mobile to 1.5.rc1 right now due to its unclear future of the project and requires a lot of migration effects.

Is there a port of Jquery-mobile 1.4.5 to support Jquery 3.2.1?

Comment: There’s no such port. Each jQM version is locked to certain jQuery version; you already understand that. There’s no other solution if you are unwilling to switch to jQM 1.5 RC1.

Comment: That is not very friendly. We just want to keep what we have right now, upgrading jquery only.

Comment: What can I tell you, jQuery Mobile is dead, or at best living dead. It's just a husk of a once-great framework and things will not get better.

Comment: what is a good replacement of Jquery mobile?

Comment: From the perspective of functionality or you wish to keep using jQuery? Overall Ionic Framework is the best current replacement. Kendo UI if you want to keep using jQuery.